# Drawing curved lines between points in ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I'm trying to plot the motion of an entity on a google map as a set of directed lines using `ggmap`. Currently I'm using the `geom_segment` call from `ggplot2` which does draw the line segments. However where there are cycles in the motion such as `1->2->1` the lines overlap. This makes it harder to figure out the motion from the visualization.

Is there a way to curve the line segments to handle this? Or are there any other approaches or libraries I could try?

Comment: There are some ideas [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216179/plot-curved-lines-between-two-locations-in-ggplot2?rq=1) and [here](http://is-r.tumblr.com/post/38459242505/beautiful-network-diagrams-with-ggplot2) that might help...

Comment: Thanks @mmk I had tried out the first link. unfortunately that approach only works with Cartesian values and I'm dealing with longitude and latitude. The 2nd link looks promising. will try it out

Comment: Please supply a minimal reproducible example to go along with your question.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're looking for are 'Bezier' curves (check wikipedia for a thorough explanation on the topic [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bézier_curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve)). In R, this is implemented using a number of different packages or you can create your own like the following:

```
 #Load dependencies
library(ggplot2)
library(maptools)
library(geosphere)

#Identify countries of interest and their centroids (see https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/fields/2011.html)
countries <- data.frame(
  Country=c("United States", "Iran"),
  ISO3=c("USA","IRN"),
  latitude=c(38,32),
  longitude=c(-97,53),
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#Get world map
data(wrld_simpl)
map.data <- fortify(wrld_simpl)

#Set up map
draw.map <- function(ylim=c(0,85)) {
  ggplot(map.data, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) +
    geom_polygon(fill="grey") +
    geom_path(size=0.1,color="white") +
    coord_map("mercator", ylim=c(-60,120), xlim=c(-180,180)) +
    theme(line = element_blank(),
          text = element_blank())
}

#Identify the points of the curve
p1 <- c(countries$longitude[1],
        countries$latitude[1])
p2 <- c(countries$longitude[2],
        countries$latitude[2])

#Create function to draw Brezier curve
bezier.curve <- function(p1, p2, p3) {
  n <- seq(0,1,length.out=50)
  bx <- (1-n)^2 * p1[[1]] +
    (1-n) * n * 2 * p3[[1]] +
    n^2 * p2[[1]]
  by <- (1-n)^2 * p1[[2]] +
    (1-n) * n * 2 * p3[[2]] +
    n^2 * p2[[2]]
  data.frame(lon=bx, lat=by)
}

bezier.arc <- function(p1, p2) {
  intercept.long <- (p1[[1]] + p2[[1]]) / 2
  intercept.lat  <- 85
  p3 <- c(intercept.long, intercept.lat)
  bezier.curve(p1, p2, p3)
}

arc3 <- bezier.arc(p1,p2)

bezier.uv.arc <- function(p1, p2) {
  # Get unit vector from P1 to P2
  u <- p2 - p1
  u <- u / sqrt(sum(u*u))
  d <- sqrt(sum((p1-p2)^2))
  # Calculate third point for spline
  m <- d / 2
  h <- floor(d * .2)
  # Create new points in rotated space 
  pp1 <- c(0,0)
  pp2 <- c(d,0)
  pp3 <- c(m, h)
  mx <- as.matrix(bezier.curve(pp1, pp2, pp3))
  # Now translate back to original coordinate space
  theta <- acos(sum(u * c(1,0))) * sign(u[2])
  ct <- cos(theta)
  st <- sin(theta)
  tr <- matrix(c(ct,  -1 * st, st, ct),ncol=2)
  tt <- matrix(rep(p1,nrow(mx)),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
  points <- tt + (mx %*% tr)
  tmp.df <- data.frame(points)
  colnames(tmp.df) <- c("lon","lat")
  tmp.df
}

arc4 <- bezier.uv.arc(p1,p2)

bezier.uv.merc.arc <- function(p1, p2) {
  pp1 <- p1
  pp2 <- p2
  pp1[2] <- asinh(tan(p1[2]/180 * pi))/pi * 180
  pp2[2] <- asinh(tan(p2[2]/180 * pi))/pi * 180

  arc <- bezier.uv.arc(pp1,pp2)
  arc$lat <-  atan(sinh(arc$lat/180 * pi))/pi * 180
  arc
}


arc5 <- bezier.uv.merc.arc(p1, p2)
d <- data.frame(lat=c(32,38),
                lon=c(53,-97))
draw.map() + 
  geom_path(data=as.data.frame(arc5), 
            aes(x=lon, y=lat, group=NULL)) +
  geom_line(data=d, aes(x=lon, y=lat, group=NULL), 
            color="black", size=0.5)
```

[image]

Also see http://dsgeek.com/2013/06/08/DrawingArcsonMaps.html for a more thorough explanation of Bezier curves using ggplot2