# ggplot2 - curveGrob - annotation_custom

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working on a similar problem as in

[Plot curved lines between two locations in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216179/plot-curved-lines-between-two-locations-in-ggplot2/34910762#34910762)

In brief I would like to draw an downward sloping curve from point (5,5) to (10,0) but keep on getting a one from (5,0) to (10,5).

```
require(grid)
g<-qplot(c(0,10),c(0,10))
myCurve<-curveGrob(0, 0, 1, 1, default.units = "npc",
           curvature = 0.3, angle = 90, ncp = 20, shape = 1,
           square = FALSE, squareShape = 1,
           inflect = FALSE, arrow = arrow(), open = TRUE,
           debug = FALSE,
           name = NULL, gp = gpar(col="blue", lwd=5), vp = NULL)

myCurve2<-curveGrob(0, 0, 1, 1, default.units = "npc",
           curvature = 0.3, angle = 90, ncp = 20, shape = 1,
           square = FALSE, squareShape = 1,
           inflect = FALSE, arrow = arrow(), open = TRUE,
           debug = FALSE,
           name = NULL, gp = gpar(col="red", lwd=5), vp = NULL)

g + 
  annotation_custom(grob=myCurve,0,10,0,10) + # plot from 0,0 to 10,10
  annotation_custom(grob=myCurve2,5,10,5,0) # expected a red curve from (5,5) to (10,0) 
                                            # but draws from (5,0) to (10,0).
```

[image]

How can I fix that? any change in parameters in **curveGrob**?

Comment: `annotation_custom` sets up a rectangular viewport, with no regards for the actual start/end point of the curve within this boundary. So if you want the curve to be from the top-left corner to the bottom-right, you'll need to define it in `curveGrob(0,1,1,0)`

Comment: thank you **baptiste** worked like charm