# How to prevent xlim from changing the height using geom_curve?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
data_frame(x = 1:5, x1=x+1, c = c('a','a','a','b','b')) %>% 
      ggplot() +
      geom_curve(aes(x = x, xend= x1, y = 0, yend = 0), curvature = -1.3, alpha=.2) +
    facet_wrap(~ c, ncol=1)
```

[image]
but I would like to tweak the limits of the y axis to cut the background area above ~ .1.

I tried to do this:

```
data_frame(x = 1:5, x1=x+1, c = c('a','a','a','b','b')) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_curve(aes(x = x, xend= x1, y = 0, yend = 0), curvature = -1.3, alpha=.2) +
  facet_grid(c ~ .) +
  ylim(0,.35) +
  facet_wrap(~ c, ncol=1)
```

but it simply rescales the archs based on the values in `ylim`. How can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: It seems that `geom_curve` calls `curveGrob` .. but the default argument for `default.units` is `"npc"` .. this could be the cause of the rescaling .. unfortunately, I can't find a way to pass this argument through `geom_curve`,so you will have to deal with `curveGrob` directly ... you may be intersted by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34911084/ggplot2-curvegrob-annotation-custom) and by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311917/ggplot2-the-unit-of-size)

Comment: Your code excerpt doesn't produce the first pasted plot. Did you have `+ facet_wrap(~c, ncol=1)` or something in there? Also, are you calling `library(tidyverse)` at the top? Being explicit will help answerers

Comment: @arvi1000 thanks I fixed it

Answer (score 4):

`coord_fixed()` has arguments that allow you to control precisely what you would like to have here.

See also http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/coord_fixed.html for reference.

Unfortunately, it is however not possible to use your `x` and `x1` in a dynamic way inside `coord_fixed()`.

As long as you are fine putting absolute values (`0.6` and `6.4` below), you can however do something like this:

```
data_frame(x = 1:5, x1 = x+1, c = c('a','a','a','b','b')) %>%
  ggplot(.) +
  geom_curve(aes(x = x, xend = x1, y = 0, yend = 0), curvature = -1.3, alpha = .2) +
  facet_grid(c ~ .) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 7, xlim = c(0.6, 6.4), ylim = c(0, 0.12), expand = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, 0.1))
```

Assuming this looks like what you would want it to look like, note that I set `expand = FALSE` to start `ylim` at zero, and added buffers to `xlim` (0.4) and the upper bound of `ylim`.
I have modified the default `ratio` value from 1 to 7, to scale you back down from the 0.7 to 0.1, which is what I understand you would like to have in the end. `ratio = 1` would imply that you have the same scale (same distances) on the y-axis as on the x-axis (which is what you refer to as *re-scaling* I believe).

Finally I had to add the manual breaks for the y-axis (to have fewer ones), such that the grid boxes would be a bit larger, which again is just what I infer as your possible wish.

Answer (score 3):

Does replacing `ylim(0,.35)` with      `coord_fixed(ylim=c(0, 0.35))` do what you want?

Comment: If I use ~.7 instead of .35 it works for me because I am mapping no variable to the y axis, thus it visually does what I need. However, it still rescales the heights of my archs, which is a bitt odd to me.